Understanding transaction of these bitcoin buyers
I'm almost positive this is a dumb question, but here goes.
I want to buy bitcoin with an ebay gift card, so I start looking at buyers and notice these two.
From my understanding, the buyer on the left is going to give me 0.00092408 for a $100 ebay gift card, while the one to the right will give me 0.00104729. From my understanding, the 2nd buyer is a better deal since I'm getting more bitcoin (0.00104729 > 0.00092408), right?
But then the one with the "better" deal has a lower margin (50% vs 70% above market), and the bitcoin value for the buyer with the "better" deal is less than the other buyer ($95,484.37 vs $108,215.62).
I know I'm missing something, what is it?
Btw, it's localcoinswap.com. It's a legal site.
Thanks.


Anything associated with Bitcon and its ilk is borderline illegal.  The industry is nothing but fraud.  You can get some nice cat sweaters on ebay that are far more valuable.


I know I'm missing something, what is it?

That maybe the web site where this is offered is a scam, and they put up random numbers that don't make any sense because they don't need to make sense? How you are you going to enforce them adding the Bitcoin to your wallet after you give them the gift card number?
Note that variations of the scam run both ways: offering to sell Bitcoin for gift cards, or offering to sell gift cards for Bitcoin. The way the scam works is that once you transfer the Bitcoin or given them the gift card numbers you have no way to undo the transfer, have no way to force them to complete their part of the deal, and realistically, no prospect of engaging the legal system to force them to cough up what they promised.
Edit: On a closer look the numbers actually do make sense: $108k/Bitcoin is close to 70% over the current market price, and $95k/Bitcoin is close to 50% over the current market place. What you are missing is that the margin here refers to how much more you are paying for the Bitcoin over the current market price. Unless you are selling stolen gift cards I don't know why you'd be willing pay so much above the market value for the Bitcoin.
My comments about a scam still stand. Note the conditions of the trader on the left:

Please wait a few minutes after the card has been sent. When I finish
loading the card I will quickly release the BTC

Yeah, "Trust me bro". I predict that if you go through with this you'll never hear from them again after they have the gift card number.

Thanks for the answer, but I'm not that naive. This site's localcoinswap.com, and I went through the due diligence of checking it out before opening the account.

And it's not a stolen card. I got it as a gift, but I rarely use ebay.

But I understand what you mean. I'm paying 70% above market value, and that makes sense.
